# How to search for plain text in cloudwatch logs insights?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I need to be able to search for certain errors using Cloudwatch logs insights.

I tried to use parse syntax but failed to get any results.

Sample error logs from my forever log

> StatusCodeError: 400 - "[{"errorCode":400002,"message":"Field Validation Error","details":"Missing mandatory field dbc.","type":"REQUEST_ERROR","field":"dbc"}]"
> at new StatusCodeError (/home/ubuntu/admin-portal-backend/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:32:15)
> [2019-07-28T06:37:21.961Z] ERROR: Admin API/12643 on ip-172-31-72-36: 400 - "[{"errorCode":400002,"message":"Field Validation Error","details":"Missing mandatory field dbc.","type":"REQUEST_ERROR","field":"dbc"}]" (req_id=f141a42d-235f-4a0e-af84-a5264fd251bf)
> StatusCodeError: 400 - "[{"errorCode":400002,"message":"Field Validation Error","details":"Missing mandatory field dbc.","type":"REQUEST_ERROR","field":"dbc"}]"
> at new StatusCodeError (/home/ubuntu/admin-portal-backend/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:32:15)
> [2019-07-28T06:37:23.584Z] ERROR: Admin API/12643 on ip-172-31-72-36: 400 - "[{"errorCode":400002,"message":"Field Validation Error","details":"Missing mandatory field dbc.","type":"REQUEST_ERROR","field":"dbc"}]" (req_id=4716a8b8-c22a-48af-a371-84ebdac741d2)
> StatusCodeError: 400 - "[{"errorCode":400002,"message":"Field Validation Error","details":"Missing mandatory field dbc.","type":"REQUEST_ERROR","field":"dbc"}]"
> at new StatusCodeError (/home/ubuntu/admin-portal-backend/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:32:15)
> [2019-07-28T06:37:24.482Z] ERROR: Admin API/12643 on ip-172-31-72-36: 400 - "[{"errorCode":400002,"message":"Field Validation Error","details":"Missing mandatory field dbc.","type":"REQUEST_ERROR","field":"dbc"}]" (req_id=aca7bbbc-7247-4845-94ef-76ed6abddbc1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change Row to **Text** to access the logs as plain text:
[image]

Then search in the search field:
[image]

Answer (score 119):

Searching on a massive amount of logs in the cloudwatch logs console can be pretty slow, which is where cloudwatch logs insights comes in.

If you want to search for a specific string in cloudwatch logs insights you could do something like

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /your text to search/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

Comment: this answer should be accepted instead, thanks @maafk

Comment: Thanks, this works! Just beware to adjust the `timespan` in AWS logs insights. By default, it searches only for the last 1 hour.

Comment: What if I want to search 2 message fields in a single query?